# How to dump the dmesg AKA Kernel logs to a single .txt file from the kernel boot?

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, drivers, debugging

I am trying to understand the SATA Host-Device Communication and for that I have put a lot of debug messages in the kernel driver code.
Now messages are in such a huge amount that I am not able to see the initial messages of the device enumeration in the dmesg log. For the same I have modified CONFIG_LOG_BUF_SHIFT(=21) config variable to increase the ring buffer size from where dmesg takes the message but still I am facing the same issue.

So, Is there any method available by which I can log all the dmesg from the kernel boot in to a specific file?

Thanks for the Help in advance.

Comment: Do you have `journalctl`? `sudo journalctl  -b 0` shows all logs since boot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
cat /var/log/dmesg > file.txt
```

and use:

```
head /var/log/dmesg
```

if you want to see the first lines of dmesg.

See too 'man head' for more specifications.
The '>' symbol redirect the ouput of 'cat' to the 'file.txt'

Comment: Thanks for the reply this method I know and tried but it didn't help I want all the messages from start of dmesg. e.g. from "[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset"

Answer (score 0):

There is a command called `dmesg` which will print the logs to stdout. You can just redirect stdout to a text file.

```
dmesg > /path/to/dmesg.txt
```

You could extend this. A really useful option would be to add a line to your `~/.profile` file (in your home directory) which appends the output of dmesg on login. Simply add a line which says:

```
dmesg >> /path/to/dmesg.txt
```

If you just want the first few lines (0.000000 messages) you can pipe it into `head` like so.

With stdout:

```
dmesg | head
```

or with `head` on an already saved .txt file.

```
head /path/to/dmesg.txt
```

That's pretty much it, hope this helps!

**EDIT:** BTW, this does contain the 0.000000 messages